# Using Power BI to create specifc columns (both headers and data within the header), based on specific conditions in other columns

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerquery, calculated-columns

I first started this with VBA, and I have been advised to use PowerBI.
However, I do not really no if my issue can be solved through powerBI.

I have a file which will be send on a recurring basis, with specific information which need to be grouped. I am trying to create a VBA macro to automate the file preparation and make it suitable for import in another tool.

I have about 40 columns, but sometimes less. The place of columns sometimes change, I thus cannot refer to column place (A, B, C...) I have to look for the column name.

Also, I have to look for some specific column. If these columns have data, I need to add specific element for each cases to the previously concatenated columns.

I am providing sample code below

Here is a dummy data description:

```
| Client | ID | Info Superman | Info Product type | Spec 1 | Spec 2 | Spec a | Spec b | Info costumer type | Info facility type | Geography |
```

When neither "spec 1", "spec 2", "Spec a" or "Spec b" have values I need to group data in the following way (including headers): "Client"+"Superman"+Bravo+"Info costumer type"+Info facility type" i.e ClientSpermanBravoInfo

If there is a value for Spec 1 or 2 : "Client""Superman"AlphaBravo"Info costumer type"Info facility type"

If there is a value for Spec 1 or 2 and Spec a and b: "Client""Superman"AlphaAlphaBravo"Info costumer type"Info facility type".

So far, I have the following VBA code, but using PowerBI would provide a simpler and more elegant solution. I have been looking at resources close to that one for example : https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-april-update-feature-summary/ in order to query data in specific way, and create columns based on specific conditions, but the I cannot find the solution.

```
Dim data


        data = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value
    End With


    Dim result As Dictionary
    Set result = New Dictionary
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        Select Case True
            Case _
                data(i, headers("Costumer")) = "" Or _
                data(i, headers("Zone ")) = "" Or _
                    MsgBox "Empty row"
                    Exit For
            Case _
                data(i, headers("Spec A")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec B")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec_C ")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec_D ")) = ""
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        q & "Costumer" & data(i, headers("Costumer”)) & _
                        q & "Alpha" & _
                        q & "Zone" & data(i, headers("Zone")) & _
                          q
            Case _
                data(i, headers("Spec_1")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec_2")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec_3")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec_4")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec_5")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec_6")) = "" And _
                data(i, headers("Spec_7")) = ""
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        q & "Costumer" & data(i, headers("Costumer")) & _
                        q & "Alphabet" & _
                        q & "Zone" & data(i, headers("Zone")) & _
                        q
            Case Else
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        q & " Costumer" & data(i, headers("Costumer ")) & 
                        q & "AlphabetAlpha" & _ 
                        q & " Zone " & data(i, headers("Zone")) & _
                        q
        End Select

    Next
    ' output result data to sheet 2
    If result.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No result data for output"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(result.Count).Value = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(result.Items())
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"



Sub TralaNome()

    Const q = """"

    ' get source data table from sheet 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

   ' check if data exists
        If .Rows.Count < 2 Or .Columns.Count < 2 Then
            MsgBox "No data table"
            Exit Sub
        End If

   ' retrieve headers name and column numbers dictionary
        Dim headers As Dictionary
        Set headers = New Dictionary
        Dim headCell
        For Each headCell In .Rows(1).Cells
            headers(headCell.Value) = headers.Count + 1
        Next

   ' check mandatory headers

        For Each headCell In Array(("Costumer", "ID", "Zone“,  "Product Quali", "Spec A", "Spec B", "Spec_C", "Spec_D", "Spec_1",  " Spec_2", " Spec_3", " Spec_4", " Spec_5", " Spec_6", " Spec_7", "Chiavetta", "Tipo_di _prodotto",  "Unicorno_Cioccolato", “cacao tree“)
            If Not headers.Exists(headCell) Then
                MsgBox "Header '" & headCell & "' doesn't exists"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        Dim data

 ' retrieve table data
        data = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Value
    End With

   ' process each row in table data
    Dim result As Dictionary
    Set result = New Dictionary
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
                    MsgBox "Empty row"
                    Exit For
                    result(result.Count) = _
                        q & "ID " & data(i, headers("ID ")) & _
                        q & " Tipo_di _prodotto " & data(i, headers("Tipo_di _prodotto")) & _
                        q & " Unicorno_Cioccolato " & data(i, headers("Unicorno_Cioccolato")) & _
                        q & " cacao tree " & data(i, headers("cacao tree "))&_qEnd Select

    Next

    ' output result data to sheet 2
    If result.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No result data for output"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(result.Count).Value = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose(result.Items())
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"


     End Sub


   Sub NewColumnNames()

   Dim OrignialColumnNames As String
   Dim a As Integer
   Dim NewColumnNames As Integer


   Spec A = Amber A 
  Spec_B = Amber B
  Spec_C = Amber C
  Spec_D = Amber D
  Spec_1 = Zio_1
  Spec_2 = Zio_2
  Spec_3 = Zio_3
  Spec_4 = Zio_4
  Spec_5  = Zio_5
  Spec_6 = Zio_6
  Spec_7 = Zio_7
  Noup_Start = Mip_F
  Noup_End = Nip_D
  Snouba = Snup_N
  SnipChocolat = Choco_F

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a PowerQuery instead of PowerBI answer, if the data was loaded into powerquery (Data .... From Table/Rage ... [x] my table has headers) then adding a simple custom column would probably do it.

Add Column ... Custom Column ... with formula similar to below; it combines columns using the & character based on the values of other columns in that row, regardless of where those columns appear or how many columns there are

```
= if [Spec 1]=null and [Spec 2]=null then [Client]&" "&[ID]&" "&[Info Superman] else
if [Spec 1]<>null and [Spec 2]<>null then [Info Product type]&" "&[Info Superman] else
null
```

You could then use Transform ... Group By ... to group on that column, and save back to the workbook with File... Close and Load...

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand this specific point: "Your question mixes all sorts of column names which makes it hard to follow along (there is no column called 'spec', for example, for us to look at only 'spec 1', 'spec 2', 'spec a' and 'spec b')."